# order of processing of text files in python

Tags: python-3.x

a small part of my code is dedicated to unzipping a zip file and looking for certain things in text files. The problem I am facing right now is that python processes the text files in a certain order in my system but it seems to use another order when the code is run on my professor's system. That order of processing is critical for what the code is trying to do. It processes the files in the correct order in my system but doesn't on his, consequently resulting in wildly different outputs. My OS is open SUSE 15.0,his is open SUSE 15.1 he runs python 3.6.9, I run 3.6.5. 
I tried downloading everything from github and running the code on my end but still cannot reproduce the issue he is having.

For what its worth, here is the list of modules I am using.

```
os,errno,sys,logging,shutil,argparse,pandas, zipfile
```

What are some possible reasons for this kind of discrepancy?

Comment: No idea about the cause, but have you considered sorting the list of files to be processed in python code itself before actually processing them?

Comment: good point. I have since discovered that OS walk is the problem. I am going to have sort the files in a certain order in order to stop this randomness. Thank you for the suggestion.